# Script works for others, not for me (error: self.fp = io.open(file, filemode) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied)

Tags: python, python-3.x, errno

I am trying to run the code below in order to extract zip files from a folder and its subfolders to another folder. I have a script that extracts my files correctly but not the ones under the subfolder. I asked the question here and been redirected to an answer from SO that I'll be adding below. People are saying it's working for them but it's giving me an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BerkayTok/PycharmProjects/GeoPandas/MergeAnswer3.py", line 7, in <module>
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\playground\lib\zipfile.py", line 1207, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\My_Dataset`

What can I try to manage this error?

```
import shutil
import zipfile

my_dir = r"D:\Download"
my_zip = r"D:\Download\my_file.zip"

with zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip) as zip_file:
    for member in zip_file.namelist():
        filename = os.path.basename(member)
        # skip directories
        if not filename:
            continue

        # copy file (taken from zipfile's extract)
        source = zip_file.open(member)
        target = open(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")
        with source, target:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Comment: your trying to access or modify a file that is being used, try to take tha last 3 rows all the way left, and make sure that none of the files your moving is open at your computer

Comment: Thank you I deleted indents on the lines that start with source, target and with (kept the indent after the with) also checked that files are not in use by my computer but still getting the same error. I also tried restarting the computer just in case something got stuck somewhere, same results. I can run another script that unzips the files and it works without giving me the error. But not this one.

Answer (score 0):

you have make sur that your file is not open

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).